# ClassicThesis: section title longer than dots

Tags: tocloft, classicthesis

I am using classicthesis for my document.
The TOC however has issues for some subsections, as they run out of the dotted lines.
[image]

How can this be fixed? If reducing the inter-word spacing i spossible then this would be the best option 
if it runs over by 1 char, otherwise also a linebreak is fine...

This is an example code (not the one from my manuscript), but it also runs over the dots:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,
headinclude,footinclude,cleardoublepage=empty,abstract=on,
BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}

\input{classicthesis-config}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{american} 

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsc{\thesection}\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}

\chapter{Bla}

\section{Blub}

\subsection{Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: MWE has been added. This seems to be a general problem. Also AAron Turons thesis is suffering from it: http://aturon.github.io/academic/turon-thesis.pdf. From the to tocloft documentation \cftsetrmarg should help, but it has no effect. Increasing cftsetpnumwidth also does not help and just ends the line earlier... Whatever the means, but there has to be some option to make no line in the toc longer than the last dot...

Comment: I made some progress using ```%Reduce TOC space after subsection number
\addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{-1mm}

%Force a minimum number of dots in the toc leaders
\renewcommand\cftchapleader{\leaders\hbox to0.33em{\hss.\hss}\hskip 0.99em plus1fill}
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\leaders\hbox to0.33em{\hss.\hss}\hskip 0.99em plus1fill}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecleader{\leaders\hbox to0.33em{\hss.\hss}\hskip 0.99em plus1fill}``` This way at least two dots are in the leader and then the words get hyphenated. Are there downsides?

Comment: @Elarion Well done. However your code does reduce the spacing between the dots in the leader. You could do `\newcommand{\mindotsleader}{\leaders\hbox to0.33em{hss.hss}\hskip 0.99em plusifill}` and then simply `\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\mindotsleader}` and similarly for the other divisional commands. Perhaps change `\mindotsleader` to give the normal dotted spacing.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Actually I achieved best looks by using 0.84em plus1fill. So my current approach is a bit depending on playing with values, however I actually like the narrow spacing of the dots. The downside is that I have no idea what the original problem is/was and why the code seems to fix it....